# What caused Community ♦ to reject this particular edit suggestion?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

When does the Community♦ "user" reject suggested edits? What was bad about this particular suggested edit, please?

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/258612

Comment: Strange.. The other stuff its rejected seems OK as well. Bot on the loose?

Comment: When a reviewer clicks Improve instead of Accept or Reject, and then unchecks the "Suggested edit was helpful" box before finishing the edit, the suggestion will show up as rejected by Community rather than the user who ended up making the edit. (Partial dupe of [the FAQ on suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/131713).)

Comment: @Pop: but in that case, the reviewer should appear in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10486950/revisions), should e not?

Comment: Yes indeed, @JacquesCousteau. I went to check out the revision history right after posting my comment, and now I'm stumped. Perhaps there was a race condition of some kind with two suggested edits? That's pretty far out though, there's probably a more reasonable explanation.

Comment: @Pop: Clashing suggestions is the only thing I can think of. Similar things have happened before.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [Tim Stone pointed out in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/958979#958979), you suggested your edit about two minutes after the initial post was made. It's possible that the OP "ninja-edited" within his five minute grace period and overrode your suggestion.