# Confused as to why a suggestion was rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I don't care about the measly 2 points I didn't get.  ***I only care about the lesson and reason*** behind the decision so I won't repeat the mistake... so that eventually, when I have enough reputation/maturity/trust to edit without supervision, I'd like to not piss off the rest of the community.

Here's [my suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/259481).

Now, I've read the [rules on post Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) and I believe I understand them (or at least the spirit behind those rules).  I've also perused similar [questions/discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106867/what-are-the-rejection-reasons-for-suggested-edits) here on Meta.

I believe I was adding some useful formatting which aided in accurately understanding the question at hand without requiring multiple read-throughs:

- It's not obvious to me what the URL following the codeblock was.  It's the sample output. (This happens twice)
- The last paragraph isn't a paragraph but an error message... So I formatted it as such.
- There was no other *obvious* typos or grammar mistakes to fix.

The fact that it was the [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user brings me to believe my error should be obvious but I simply don't get it.  There's no message.  Nothing!  I simple, automated *"F#$% off! You don't know how to edit!"* (actually it just says **Rejected** but without any reasons to explain, it might aswell be written that)

I would like to be able to serve the community better so... please explain to me which law I've obviously broken.  If I can't properly serve this community then it's a moot point for me to stick around isn't it.

Comment: Beats me, I would've accepted it.

Comment: I wouldn't let it get to you - According to your edit stats you have 117 accepted and only 2 rejected, certainly not a reason to leave the community :)

Comment: Post owner edited himself, that overrules suggested edits, at least if the owner edit is more substantial. The lesson to learn: better timing ;)

Comment: [Community♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is a dick; have you seen how they vote?! I'd ignore him/her/it.

Comment: I have no intention, to leave the community right now (muahaha!). But having things — anything — fail without no stated _reasons_ is ***very*** frustrating.

Comment: The same, or a very similar, thing happened yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131702/what-caused-community-to-reject-this-particular-edit-suggestion

Comment: Going to suggest this changes : [Odd scenario which doesn't give a Rejected reason and should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131901/172556)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like [Tanner Ewing edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10501418/6) at about the same time your [suggested edit came along](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/259481), and potentially marked it as Unhelpful<sup>*[See Comments]*</sup>, and thus it was rejected by Community.

[image]

I don't think you did anything wrong, and it appears Tanner (inadvertently) kept most of your changes and added some additional information.

Comment: I thought that, but notice that Qwerty and Tanner's edits use identical messages. It looks to me like Tanner "improved" Qwerty's edit but marked it as "not helpful". I think that's possible for a 49-rep user if they own the post. Is there any way to verify?

Comment: Yeah I don't know, I'm not low enough on the totem pole on either this site or that site to check. My gut says Tanner didn't have to provide any reason and they got ninja-merged. My gut also says its getting to be dinner time, so barring a developer's answer I'm just guessing.

Comment: Then there should have, at least something in the line of _"The original author of the post has edited the post before your suggestion could be approved by peers"_  I have no problems receiving such message because it keeps me informed.