# Should the Rejected Edit reason be shown to the Editor?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)
>   [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)
>   [Confused as to why a suggestion was rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131844/confused-as-to-why-a-suggestion-was-rejected)

Is there a reason that the editor of a rejected edit cannot see the reason an edit was rejected?

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/299082

Comment: Or rather: possible duplicate of [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127375)

Comment: Here is another example.. This is flat out rejected but the current version has no edits. http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/301915  No Explaination.

Comment: That one could have been an edit by the OP, within the grace period, so there's no record of that. Seems to happen to you unusually often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you can see the rejection reason on the suggested-edit page. An exception is when there is no rejection reason, which happens if the first reviewer decides to improve your edit and marks the suggestion as not helpful. Then the edit is rejected by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) without reason.

The actual reason for the reviewer to mark the suggestion as not helpful is probably one of

- it's incorrect
- it's way too minor, there's much more to fix

which applies, you can sort-of infer by going to the post and comparing the actual edit with your suggestion.

In this case, though, I suspect something else happened, since the actual edit is pretty much identical to your suggestion:

A user with edit privileges started to edit before you submitted your suggestion and submitted it after you, causing your suggestion to be auto-rejected.

Comment: 1st - is a rejected edit considered a negative?  2nd if it is couldnt this cause a new user trying to learn to edit to become frustrated and stop?

Comment: Another case when an edit is rejected by Community is if someone else starts editing before the suggested edit is submitted and finished editing after the suggested edit is submitted. This is probably what happened here. @Jake1164 A rejected edit is normally considered a negative, but not here: if someone else edited at the same time, it sure isn't your fault.

Comment: @Jake1164 Ye-es, sort of. One rejected suggestion isn't bad at all, except you don't get the 2 rep points for it. If you have a lot of rejections, you get a suggestion ban for a week. But I don't think you have to fear that, your suggestion looks good quality.

Comment: I can accept an answer in 3 min?

Comment: @Jake1164 15 minutes after posting your question.

Comment: @Gilles I am not after the points or worried about myself, this is more of a 'for good the community' and sake of those who follow.

Comment: @Jake1164 [Suggested edit rejections for concurrent edits should not count for the suggested edit ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137611)

Comment: I think this happens alot more often: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/302146