# Suggested edit rejections for concurrent edits should not count for the suggested edit ban

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Sometimes a suggested edit is [rejected (by Community)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits) because of a concurrent direct edit that takes precedence.

Since this is no fault of the edit suggestor, such rejections should not count against the suggestor when counting [rejections for bad edits that lead to a ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days).

Here are some examples where it happened:

- [Access denied for edit posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147021/access-denied-for-edit-posts/147072)
- [My edits got rejected because I edited at the same time as another user, now I can't make edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177568/my-edits-got-rejected-because-i-edited-at-the-same-time-as-another-user-now-i-c)

Comment: Should be a badge for asking a question that causes a feature request ;)

Comment: I agree, but I doubt that's an actual problem. I think those rejections are so rare that a decent editor won't get pushed near the limit by them. Some real numbers would be nice to have, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer [Here's a case where it happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147021/access-denied-for-edit-posts/147072). In high-activity tags on [so], a question can get multiple editors falling over each other's heels during its first minutes, when it's on the front page.

Comment: So it _is_ an actual problem (small in numbers, but getting suggestion-banned for that is quite unfair). Whom shall we blackamil to get the request implemented?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We now ignore any suggested edits that were rejected by the [Community User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) due to an edit conflict when determining whether someone should be banned from submitting suggested edits. [These rejections are annotated with a description of what happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit):

[image: Conflicted with a subsequent edit]

Aside from rejecting "concurrent" edits, the Community User also rejects edits that are *intentionally replaced* when the "Reject and Edit" option is used in review. [As of September 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) these *do* count toward edit bans ([and warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334)), as these rejections are not accidental and *can* generally be avoided by submitting more appropriate/substantive edits. These rejections are also annotated:

[image: This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.]

Comment: @Shog9 Btw, can you ban Community? Just curious.

Comment: Seems like this is broken. Community rejected edits still show up

Comment: Appears to be buggy: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361838/the-site-is-threatening-me-with-edit-suspension-over-automated-rejections-caused?cb=1

Comment: Appears to be fixed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362096/18595321