# Why was my suggested edit (which adds a new tag) rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This is my suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2475066 and this is the question: [Receiving "syntax error, unexpected '<'" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558314/mysql-error-help-me-please).

I wanted to know why was it rejected, since I think this is clearly php and php related.

Comment: Ah, I think someone with editing privileges stepped on your suggestion with their own edit.  See http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17558314/2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this was because there was another more substantial edit that was made while yours was awaiting approval.  There's nothing wrong with adding the PHP tag to that question, but there were other problems that needed to be addressed.  It's confusing, I know, but when the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) account rejects your edit, it's usually because another edit overrode yours.

Comment: The timestamps seem to back that up: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17558314/revisions . Floris' edit came at the same time as this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was really useful. The bad thing is that now I have +1 number of rejected edits and also someone edited the question after reading this post and his edit was accepted...

Comment: I've been seeing more and more of these unexplained Community rejections lately.

Comment: @Undo there is nothing unexplained about it.  When Community rejects an edit, it is either (1) someone improved a suggested edit and unchecked "this edit was helpful" or (2) someone with full edit privileges (OP, or >2Ker)  submitted an edit before the suggested edit was approved.  If you are seeing more recently, it's only because more of these occurrences are happening.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think he means it's not explained on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2475066).  It just shows up as **Rejected**.  They probably could tack a short explanation on there.

Comment: @BilltheLizard oh ok.. the way it is worded, I wasn't sure.  I agree the community rejections could use more detail.

Comment: Possibly it shouldn't be "Rejected" at all. As that has a clear negative connotation. Perhaps "Cancelled" or "No longer current" and it shouldn't show up in the rejected vs accepted statistics

Comment: @RichardTingle [Community-rejected suggestions no longer count when calculating bans.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, good to know this.