# Is there a penalty for editing posts continuously in a row?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I fix grammar from posts a lot, mostly just with the title and a few bits of characters. If I keep doing this, will I get a ban or a penalty of some kind?  I keep my edits good; they are fixed right and my edits rarely get rejected (usually only when the person is being ignorant).  Adding on to that, if to many edits get rejected, is there a penalty?

Comment: I have actually experienced that "ignorant" part yesterday, which wasn't too comforting.  Other than that, there are other instances where an edit can be overwritten, causing an automatic rejection (usually by Community).  Such cases include submitting a suggestion within the OP's grace period (first five minutes of post submission).  Doing so can get your suggestion rejected with the OP's next edit (without anyone else knowing).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the extra information @Jamal

Comment: I have one in mind for screwing up my personalized front page.  That's where it will have to stay unfortunately.

Comment: Regarding your edit then yes, as the accepted answer quotes if too many edits are rejected you get banned from editing for 7 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, if they are proper edits.

I used to do that a lot too on Stack Overflow.  I never got penalized (I never did have many rejected edits though).  As long as they are proper edits, keep on the good work!

---

I did find another similar question on Meta:

> [Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected)

Here is what [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) had to say:

> No, but repeated edit suggestion rejections from multiple users will
>   cause your edit suggestion rights to be suspended for (n) days, where
>   n is currently 7.
>
> Note that after a recent change, rejections done by the Community user
>   [are ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/152859) and won't
>   affect the suggested edit ban mechanism. (only rejections made by
>   actual users)

Answer (score 12):

While what syb0rg said is true in general, I had a look at a few of your recent suggested edits and I have some concerns about them.

Personally, I would have rejected these edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3705304
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3705188
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3705137
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3704747

because all you did there was change the capitalization style of the title, and you changed it to a style that isn't used here, and frankly looks quite odd. That isn't a significant edit, or an improvement of grammar, so I would suggest avoiding such edits in the future and instead focusing on more significant problems with questions.

For example, this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3705101 did improve some of the capitalization in the body of the question, but left a lot of other problems alone. Rather than fixating on the title, I'd recommend trying to correct the larger issues with the wording in a question like that.

The reviewers who rejected these weren't "being ignorant", they were most likely suggesting that these were not great edits, for the reasons I described above.

Comment: JavaScript and CSS is fine, but other than that you're right, Not Every Word in Title should be capitalized.