# Rejected edits by Community should not show up anywhere

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

A bunch of my edits were rejected by Community as

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

However, when I try to edit something, it says:

> [image]

Also,

> [image]

5 of those are Community rejects due to conflicts.

Shouldn't the Community rejects not show up?

These are the rejected edits (as of now):

- [Rejected Edit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8725261)
- [Rejected Edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8720251)
- [Rejected Edit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8791579)
- [Rejected Edit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8809153)
- [Rejected Edit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8849697)
- [Rejected Edit 6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8852058)

Comment: Yea, they should minus those conflicts from the total rejections. Since if you're a user that suggests edits to newer/active posts mainly, you'll have way higher editing conflicts than a user who only suggests edits on older posts. At least those rejections [don't count against you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/244519). I don't think they should show that message if caused by those conflict rejections. Or link to relevant meta post.. with link text of "may be rejected for many reasons outside your control"

Comment: Isn't there still a bug pending on those editor stats? I'm amazed you managed to get a coherent analysis of where your stats come from.

Comment: @rene that may only apply to reviewer stats, not sure though

Comment: You might read it as suggestion to wait with editing till the flurry of edits on a new question has died down. Or to wait with editing new content till you have enough rep to do it without having to wait for community approval.

Comment: "*Shouldn't the community rejects not show up?*" -- it will cause confusion amongst the users, because that "Attention!" isn't going to disappear anywhere which means the user would end up thinking which edit of him/her was rejected (I used to suggest  lots of edits before reaching 2k+ points on [Android.se], and considering your demand, I definitely would have been left scratching my head for some of Community rejected messages)? I think they should remain. Alternatively, I advise changing your strategy of editing the posts.

Comment: Instead of having them not show up anywhere, I think you should ask for: Community rejected edits resulted from some sort of  conflicts (usually subsequent edit) shouldn't be counted for the user, so as to avoid getting that "Attention!".

Answer (score 6):

You should've gotten a warning, but not *this* warning. [There was a bug that caused the warning logic to count conflict-rejections when it shouldn't have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361838/the-site-is-threatening-me-with-edit-suspension-over-automated-rejections-caused/362096#362096).

But you probably should've still seen *one* warning for [the one edit that was rejected by ordinary reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334).