# Reasoning blurb for community actions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-user

Lots of times, Community♦ does stuff like unlocking posts, approving edits, etc.

A lot of these are confusing to someone looking at the revision history. Community rejecting edits has cropped up [once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131702/what-caused-community-to-reject-this-particular-edit-suggestion) or [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits) on MSO.

It would be nice if Community♦ gave a reason for its actions. For example, when it unlocks a timed lock, it should say "removing timed lock after xyz hours" in the revision history.

**An alternative solution would be a detailed [faq] post on what Community♦ can do and what the possible reasons are for an action.**

Comment: [Community's profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) already has a list, and there's an [existing FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) about it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Its incomplete then. The approving/unlocking/etc. I said _extensive_, and only an SE-ite can do that.

Comment: What does a post being unlocked have to do with the Community user? Wouldn't it be just as confusing if a normal moderator had unlocked a post? Why did *they* do it? Moderator/user actions can be just as confusing. Also, when it comes to Community approving/rejecting suggested edits, that's just poor design IMO. I've already suggested a workaround that gives credit to the actual user when they improve the post, which would get rid of most of Community's involvement in suggested edits.