# yet another "rejected suggested edit"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have suggested this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/860511) on answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019922/is-there-a-popular-name-for-this-bit-related-expression/13020014). It got rejected 3:2, interestingly, by the more experienced editors with the following reason:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post

My question of course is: why in the world was it rejected? And can something be done now, since I hadn't seen the somewhat mentioned  "resubmit edit" option anywhere?

It was not an [OP ninja edit situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131706/197422).
To [quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142161/197422) kiamlaluno from a related question:

> If you look at the "how to edit" block shown when you suggest an edit, you will notice it shows the following points:
>
> - fix grammatical or spelling errors
> - clarify meaning without changing it
> - correct minor mistakes
> - **add related resources or links**
> - always respect the original author

Those guidelines are still in SO edit user interface. I did exactly what was suggested - added a valuable link on the *existing* text. Also, there isn't a single link on the entire thread.

The only logical explanation that I am able to produce is that the link links to the "common masking operations" and that is not *very narrowly* related to question topic (all bits set) - but that makes no sense since setting all bits *is* a masking operation and suggested link content is correctly related to the (part of the) answer I tried to edit.

Please advise.

*disclaimer: 

I believe that the editors made a mistake (which is quite natural for human beings :) ) and I'd like to see it corrected if possible. On the other hand, if my reasoning is wrong I'd like to know how it is wrong in order not to make such mistakes anymore.*

Comment: Not sure I would have gone for the same reject reason, but it seems "too  minor" in my opinion.

Comment: Most likely if I was going through suggested edits and saw that one pop up, I would have thought "this isn't even an answer" and rejected the edit since the link doesn't really make it an answer either.

Comment: The question itself is very simple, and consequently so is that answer and my edit to it. And it is not closed. Interesting thing is that on this question I got +10/-8 score. The community is obviously very polarized about the subject.

Comment: The question should be closed. It's mostly an [identify-this] question.

Comment: @animuson That clarifies the situation. Thanks for input :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an edge case. On one hand, you do add a link that might be useful; on the other hand, why not linking all other words on all other posts? If you start such thing, it will never end.

Personally I would also reject such edit for the reason above.

That said, there is no option to "resubmit" suggested edit but if you truly believe it should be done you can always do this again, hoping that other users will review. The system knows to protect itself of course, after several rejected edits you'll be blocked from suggesting any further for several days.

Comment: Bit of a moot point, but would "too minor" not have been a better fit in your opinion?

Comment: @Bart no. Adding a link is not minor; either it's valid or invalid. That's how I see it.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I don't read them like that, but in the end I would have rejected it as well.

Comment: accept for "egde case" (the only thing that is not unclear to me in all the answers/comments). OK I suppose that I'll just have to apply the trial and error method. Is there a possibility to view the accepted edits? Also take look at my above comment about the score of this question..

Comment: @linski view what accepted edits? If you mean the overall history then it requires certain amount of reputation, 10K if I recall correctly. As for question score yes, since this is edge case some people agree and some disagree here on Meta +1/-1 means exactly this.

Comment: @linski I'm one of the ones who rejected that edit. This answer explains why; I felt that with only one of the three linked, it actually changed the meaning. It was a bad answer to begin with, too, and to be honest, the edit did not really improve it.

Comment: @Andrew animuson stated similar in comment - both of you clarified the situation for me, thanks. I'm not 100% for it, but I can agree that it is not the real/good answer/question. Now that you said it, I see what do you mean by "changed meaning", and I can't disagree. If I'had linked all three words on that link would you still think it changed meaning? Also, would replacing the three words with a short concise explanation/definition of the term (with relevant link) improve the answer in your opinion?