# Add a reject reason when the Community user rejects an edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

When the Community user rejects an edit during the grace period there is no obvious reason visible ([example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7590)).

> Community♦ reviewed this 1 hour ago: Reject

This causes some confusion for the user who suggested the edit. See also:

- [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)
- [What caused Community ♦ to reject this particular edit suggestion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131702/what-caused-community-to-reject-this-particular-edit-suggestion)

I’m afraid these “rejects without a reason” are not helpful and rather discouraging. A short explanation would be useful, and the suggester could learn something.

Comment: Yes, I would love to be able to type: "did not fix _every_ problem with post" or "randomly highlighting words is not considered a 'good' edit"

Comment: Supporting this feature-request - happened to me as well

Comment: Future viewers, if confused, might be interested in ["Why does the Community user approve and reject edits?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/206222)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kevin whipped this up a couple of days ago. You can view an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5570964):

[image: Conflicted with a subsequent edit.]

These rejections do not count toward edit bans or [warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334).

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn’t expect an answer anymore. :) Looks good.

Comment: is this already deployed? I ask because there is a complaint at TWP meta that seems to suggest that [6 hours ago there still was an issue](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/why-did-virtual-user-community-reject-a-tag-edit) and the edit complained about doesn't show "Conflicted..." message: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20238

Comment: @gnat most likely it's only on Stack Overflow where most conflicts happen.

Comment: It is *now*, @gnat: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20277 - not sure what happened there.

Comment: [thanks!](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/why-did-virtual-user-community-reject-a-tag-edit#comment6388_2879 "fix tested, verified :)")

Comment: Its good to know these rejections don't count toward bans, but still very discouraging to see my accept/reject ratio affected by this. Under these circumstances I wish I'd never attempted the edit at all - its too bad the count doesn't work that way too.

Answer (score 37):

<strike>It's more than just discouraging, each rejection has impact on the user suggesting the edit as it might lead to a ban.</strike>
The above is no longer true, [as of June 4<sup>th</sup> 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/152859):

> We now completely ignore any suggested edits that were rejected by the Community User when determining whether someone be banned from reviewing suggested edits

This is a blessed change, however it's also worth to note that the Community user is [rejecting lots of suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=reviews), and it looks like it's on a drastic rise. For example on September 18<sup>th</sup> 2012 it rejected 59 suggested edit while on April 11<sup>th</sup> 2013 it rejected 112 suggested edit. (Just two random dates)

I agree that those poor souls deserve to know the reason why their edit got rejected, same way that flesh and blood users can choose or write a reason.

Taking a [sample case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1968308), here is a mockup that will save some tears and frustration:

> [image]

Comment: Can someone be banned for rejecting edits and degrading the post?

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me today [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13747). The edit that I suggested came 13 minutes after the question was posted so it wasn't that the question was edited within the grace period.

Also, there is no evidence to support that a reviewer improved on the post by further editing it and marking my edit as unhelpful. The post was [edited by another user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13748) at a later stage but I believe this to be unrelated.

If a reject reason was added as suggested here, it would make the process much more user friendly and potentially reduce the number of new questions being opened requesting clarification for the reject reason.

As noted in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177464/152859), the community user is rejecting quite a few suggested edits lately (examples from same user [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1931442), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1931478)). Perhaps there is some issue with it? If this behaviour continues, it will likely put people off suggesting edits and that would be a shame seeing as they are trying to improve on the quality of the content on the site.

Answer (score 6):

As **I had this happen to me today** (on [WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)), I was unsure of whether there was an inherent problem with the edit or not - obviously not.

This should be mandatory as the user being rejected might actually consider the edit to have been rejected by a real reviewer and as you suggest, with no explanation, that's discouraging.

Top suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Going to completely support this one.

A user posted a question with some unrelated tags (presumably for the purpose of making the question more visible), so I suggested an edit removing all the superfluous ones. Two real people quickly approved, and then I saw it was rejected by Community. No explanation, basically just a f**k you. This pretty much sends the message that I should stop bothering to make edits (at least until I have enough rep that I don't need them approved) - especially considering this isn't the first time one of my edits has been approved by two real people (other times more substantial than just a re-tag) and then shot down by the Community bot.

Answer (score 2):

Wholeheartedly agree with this one, it happened to be only a couple of hours ago again, it's disheartening to know that you're trying to make the question / answer better, and it gets shut down with no explanation, there's only really ever 2 possible scenarios:

1. The person disagrees with your change
2. The edit submitted was actually *wrong*

Either way, it makes sense that a reason be given, even if it's chosen from a preselected few options like when you are flagging an item, that way that editor can know the reason for the rejection (heaven forbid, even learn form it themselves)