# Explain why suggested edit is being rejected by Community

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

The Community user is [rejecting lots of suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=reviews). Each rejection has impact on the user suggesting the edit as it might lead to a ban.

Don't they at least deserve to know the reason why it got rejected, same way that flesh and blood users can choose or write a reason? I think they do.

Taking a [sample case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1968308), here is a mockup that will save some tears and frustration:

> [image]

Comment: @Bart missed that one thanks. Out of bounties for now... :-(

Comment: Done. Seems a reasonable request.

Comment: As you've done the work on a mock-up you could add this as an answer... it adds more than the current ones which only explain the reasons for a specific example.

Comment: @ben hmm.. can a question be merged as answer to other question?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Just copy paste. Perhaps change the wording slightly to make it more of an answer, but then you should be good to go.

Comment: Don't know, but you can copy and paste :-).

Comment: Thanks @Bart and ben, [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177464/152859). :-)