# My edits got rejected because I edited at the same time as another user, now I can't make edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, community-user, edit-ban

When I edit a post, same time the other user also change the post, his post is accepted and my edit is rejected. But both of the edit is same in some times. I lost the edit privileged for an week? Why?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi His latest edit wasn't rejected by a user, it was [auto-rejected by Community](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1973809). I'm slightly surprised that an automatic rejection can trigger a block.

Comment: Must say he had a lot of suggestion rejected by only Community (which means the op edited the question at the same time). That's pretty unlucky.

Comment: He's only had 4 user-rejected edits out of 21 suggestions, but has had several more auto-rejected by Community.

Comment: Even more infuriating when you spend a significant amount of time actually improving a post only to be overridden by some hasty fly-by-the-seat-of-their-pants editor, being much less constructive. The ban you received is a low blow, though.

Comment: Related feature request: [Add a reject reason when the Community user rejects an edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153403)

Comment: Kudos to you for apparently trying to carefully and thoughtfully improve posts. Hopefully this edge case will be fixed!

Comment: This is the most relevant feature-request: [Suggested edit rejections for concurrent edits should not count for the suggested edit ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste)

Comment: It might be a good idea not to edit posts during the first 5 minutes. The original poster is perhaps not done yet, and it is easy to get into the simultaneous edit problem.