# Suggested edits get rejected if someone in the mean time approves a edit?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

Do suggested edits get rejected or ignored if someone in the mean time approves a edit.

EG: I edit a post that took me a several minutes to format properly and I submit it. In the mean time while my post is getting approved the OP (sometimes small changes and even seconds after I submitted my post) or someone else makes a change to the post and it is approved. Does my post that I worked hard on just get tossed/rejected because I've never seen my post get approved after a edit was approved.

Comment: Not exactly: if user with full edit right (OP, 2K user or diamond mod) started to edit before you submitted your edit then submitted his edit after yours then there will be something known as "edit conflict" and the suggestion will be auto rejected. It happens a lot, looking for example. [Recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3702300) - it was auto rejected because OP has edited, see [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20866545/3). Edit: lol didn't notice that's your edit!

Comment: I'd also note that editing the code of someone's answer is generally not a terrific idea... especially when it's new as the OP may correct any flaws themselves... It's generally more polite to leave a comment saying something like "Did you mean to duplicate that code block" - instead of suggesting an edit to remove it...

Comment: @ShadowWizard nice find ;D So basically its an edit conflict where OP, 2K user or such submits a edit while mine is in queue and gets auto rejected. That kinda sucks because I've made several edits where I formatted a entire post and it gets rejected within a few seconds after I submitted mine because user made a small change of some sort.

Comment: @Class I can't agree more, it's happening a lot and we should at least show some friendly message, something which [is already suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit).