# Your last edit was rejected warning on a conflicting edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

When going to make a new edit, it nicely warns you that your last edit was rejected, however if your last edit was rejected because `This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit`, why does it show this message? There's usually not much you can do to avoid that.

[image: Your last edit was rejected warning]
The link: [review the reasons before rejecting it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19108476)

[image: Reject because conflicting]

Comment: What happened to the suggested edit you made *before* this one?

Comment: That's the one that was rejected because it was conflicting

Comment: I meant the one *before* that one.

Comment: This question was already asked on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316355/6083675). Please check your other edits and see if any were rejected by reviewers.

Comment: @Glorfindel My most recent edits not including the conflicting one have succeeded. I've failed two edits total for reasons that are not conflicting

Comment: The question linked to by Laurel seems to indicate it isn't. It *might* be that the rejected edit was on a post which is now deleted, but that's hard to tell without dev tools. Which site was this on?

Comment: @Glorfindel stackoverflow

Comment: Strange ... your last rejected edit is from last October ... https://stackoverflow.com/users/2821420/pfg?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: @Glorfindel The link links to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19108476

Comment: Hmm... maybe those kind of rejected edits aren't shown on your profile on purpose.

Comment: Suggested edits to deleted posts aren't shown on one's account. (cc @Glorfindel)

Comment: @Ano but do they count for the warning?

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, all rejected edits do. Also, this was actually supposedly "fixed" very recently, but I can't find the post saying so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a reject reason when the Community user rejects an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: That was [status-completed] long before this was asked, and there's no obvious explanation that its completion would make this [status-bydesign] either, so I don't think they can be dupes.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards This post is about how when you go to edit another post it will give a useless warning (the reason was the edit conflicted with another edit, I shouldn't need to be warned about that).